# How can I make my scala function faster?

Tags: java, scala

I made `isSorted` function in both **Scala** and **Java**. When I measured the execution time of both the functions, I saw that the **Scala** version was very slow. It ran about `3.2` sec for 10000 Int but Java version just ran about `10` ms!!!
How can I make faster my scala version?

These were the implementation :

Scala:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) ={
    println(isSorted(getArray, (x:Int,y:Int) => x<y ))
}
def isSorted[A](items : Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean) : Boolean = items match{
  case Array(_) => true 
  case Array(x,y) =>cond(x,y)
  case Array(_*) => cond(items(0),items(1)) && isSorted(items tail,cond)
}
```

Java:

```
public static void main(String... args){
    Sorter<Integer> sorter=new Sorter<Integer>();
    System.out.println(sorter.isSorted(sorter.getList(),new Comparator<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    }));
}
public  boolean isSorted(List<A> items, Comparator<A> cond){
    for(int i=1;i<items.size();i++){
            if(cond.compare(items.get(i-1), items.get(i)) < 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
    return true;
}
```

Any suggestion?

I know this is a weird code :)

I would like to use **Scala** but this bad performance scared me!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and should be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well you're using pattern matching in the Scala version, which is bound to be slower. If you make the two versions similar, then they will almost certainly take the same amount of time (since they will compile to the same bytecode).

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making copies of the entire array in Scala *every iteration*.  If you replace an `O(n)` algorithm with an `O(n^2)` one, of *course* that is going to be slower!  This has nothing to do with Scala vs. Java or even pattern matching.

If you want to use an algorithm with tails, switch to a data structure that supports efficient tails (e.g. `List`).

```
def isSorted[A](items: List[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = items match {
  case Nil => true
  case x :: y :: rest if (!cond(x,y)) => false
  case _ => isSorted(items.tail, cond)
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the same algorithm as with Java, since arrays are efficient with indexing:

```
def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  for (i <- 1 until items.length) if (!(cond(items(i-1),items(i)))) return false
  true
}
```

Or you could, if performance isn't super-important, switch to some generic but still `O(n)` algorithm:

```
def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean) = 
  items.sliding(2).filter(_.length == 2).forall(x => cond(x(0),x(1)))
```

This will be maybe 5x slower than the index-based version.

Comment: Could a(n array) view perform similarly? That might eliminate the need to create copies.

Comment: @GáborBakos - I try to avoid views since they are not the most stable part of the library.  In principle yes, but in practice there are better ways to solve this problem, so those should be used instead.

Comment: This is the best answer. +1

Comment: Hi! I do not know how I can migrate you answer to codreview site. Here my question and I would like to ask you to answer it here as well 
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43992/how-can-i-make-my-issorted-function-faster
Thank you!

Comment: @bitli - Eh, just link to it or copy my answer over crediting me for it or something.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I would do it, in a way that's idiomatic to Scala, more flexible, and sticks to a functional style.

```
def isSorted[A](xs: Seq[A])(cond: (A, A) => Boolean) = {
  (xs, xs.view.drop(1)).zipped.forall { case(a,b) => cond(a,b) }
}
```

Used as follows:

```
val xs = (0 to 10000).toArray
val sorted = isSorted(xs)(_ < _) // or isSorted(xs)((a,b) => a < b) if you prefer
```

This has several advantages over the original version:

- It works for *any* sequence, not just Arrays
- It completes about 500 times faster than than the version that uses array pattern matching

  - My rudimentary benchmark took about **4.6 seconds** to complete the original version, and **0.008** seconds to complete the proposed version
- The code is both shorter *and* more idiomatic
- It puts the predicate function in its own braces, meaning it will infer types for you automatically instead of making you put them in by hand. You also get _ wildcards for free.

#### Edit

With the original signature (which loses the ability to type-infer the conditional function, and restricts the type to only arrays), you would have a function that looks like this:

```
def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = { 
  (xs, xs.view.drop(1)).zipped.forall { case(a,b) => cond(a,b) }
}
```

This seems to be a couple times faster than the version that uses `sliding(2)` to turn the array into an iterator. It's not quite as speedy as using direct indexers (translating straight from Java). It's still on the order of 500 or 600 times faster than pattern matching directly on the array.

I also changed it from using a negation of `exists` to using the positive assertion of `forall`. This doesn't affect the performance, just the readability (`exists` required a double-negative, which was foolish of me).

#### Edit 2

I've added a call to `.view`, to prevent a full copy of the array for the second value. This speeds up the algorithm slightly, getting it to a point where it's *nearly* (but not quite) as fast as accessing the indices directly. The expression can still generalize to non-Array inputs, were you to ever update the function signature.

Comment: What if the signature of isSorted function were fixed?

Comment: @bitli Ignoring the fact that I accidentally renamed `cond` to `f` (oops), if you changed the signature back to `def isSorted[A](xs: Array[A], cond: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean` the body would stay the same, and the speed would stay the same. But you'd be restricted to only using arrays, and you'd have to annotate your captured variables for the condition (`isSorted(items, (a:Int, b:Int) => a < b)`). And it wouldn't be idiomatic Scala.

Comment: @bitli Updated the answer to include a version using your original signature. Most of the benefits are the same, and the speed is the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala using the *idiomatic style* is not always the most appropriate when having the performance into account. In particular, [Scala Array pattern matching is really slow](http://www.krazykoding.com/2012/05/scala-array-pattern-matching-is-really.html).

However, using the *non-idiomatic style* in this case it will [perform similar or slightly better than in Java](https://jazzy.id.au/default/2012/10/16/benchmarking_scala_against_java.html).

Here you a version of your `isSorted` algorithm but using the classic `if` conditional instead of `pattern matching`. You can run the same benchmark with this solutions and it has to be a big difference. Let me know if performs much better.

```
 def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
   if  (items.length == 1) true
   else if (cond(items(1), items(0))) false
   else { isSorted(items.tail, cond) }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add another approach, which is also O(n).

```
def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean =
  (0 until items.size - 1).forall(i => cond(items(i), items(i + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally subscribe to @Rex-Kerr answer, a possible improvement on the array indexing approach that relies on examining each end of the array for each iteration, as follows,

```
def isSorted[A](items: Array[A], cond: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  val len = items.length
  for (i <- 1 until len/2+1) 
    if (!(cond(items(i-1),items(i))) || !(cond(items(len-i-1),items(len-i))) ) return false
  true
}
```

In general, the initial array may be partitioned into n segments and apply the condition on each in parallel.

Comment: I would like to use some funcional programing approaches like pattern matching. This criteria is very important. I like fuctional programing style and I like Java as well. Thank you for answering.